# The use of enumerated options

Tags: best-practices, enumitem

I am not sure what would be the `best-practice` approach to type setting an observation that has an `enumerate` list.

For instance, consider:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
A bunch of text here. Obsevations
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\item
...
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

1. Should I set it up as shown in the MWE?
2. Should I bring it down and:

   ```
   \noindent Observations:
   \begin{enumerate}
   \item
   \end{enumerate}
   ```
3. Should I keep it as the MWE but add `:` after observations?
4. Maybe this should be inline?

I am too sure on how this would or should be handled.  Is there a universal or a few standard approaches?

---

Maybe an image of what it could look like will help (this is option 2):

[image]

Comment: I think it depends on the context, (especially) the type of document, and even the number of potential items in a list. A technical or executive summary might work better with an enumerated list (also: handouts for a talk or a list of style guidelines, etc.). As part of a prose non-fiction text (say in the conclusion to an essay), I would resist giving so much emphasis to these 'observations': I think it would set the wrong tone. Instead, I would do (at most) something like: "Several observations come to mind: (1) ...; (2) ...". If there are ten observations, however, a list might make sense!

Comment: @jon it is for notes on classical mechanics.

Comment: For your students, for a talk, or for a paper? Unless there are more than 3 observations, I would use an in-line list for a paper. For students or a talk, then a list is a clear way to draw attention to 'important' things.  The Chicago Manual of Style (15e, § 6.124) makes a similar point in more prescriptive style: "Short, simple lists are usually better run in, especially if the introduction and the items form a complete grammatical sentence (see 6.126). Lists that require typographic prominence, that are extremely long, or that contain items of several levels should be set vertically."

Comment: ... Of course, what to do when the observations are mathematical may well be quite different!  (Not my area....)